# Issue with making a swap function with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to make a swap function on my own with float pointers and it just does not work. For some reason I think I don't pass the `float` pointers to the function in the correct way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(float *a, float *b);

int main() {
    float num1 = 0.0;
    float num2 = 0.0;

    float *px = NULL;
    float *py = NULL;

    printf("Please enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    getchar();

    printf("Please enter another decimal number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    px = &num1;
    py = &num2;

    printf("The numbers before swapping - \nNum1 = %f\nNum2 = %f\n", num1, num2);

    swap(&px, &py);

    printf("\nThe numbers after swapping - \nNum1 = %f\nNum2 = %f\n\n", num1, num2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void swap(float *a, float *b) {
    float temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Delete all occurrences of `px` and `py` in this code, passing `&num1` and `&num2` to your swap instead. Or lose the `&` in front of `px` and `py` in your swap call. If you didn't get at least a warning about `float**` not being compatible with `float*` in this, I'm shocked.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. Using `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 file.c -o file.o`  the compiler output: 1) line:4: passing argument 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type  2) line 25: passing argument 2 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type 3) line4 expected 'float*' but argument is of type 'float**'.    Suggest fixing those problems before trying anything else.   Note: do not ignore warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You pass addresses of pointers to `float` instead of just addresses of `float` values.  Remove the `px` and `py` variables and simplify your call to:

```
swap(&num1, &num2);
```

The compiler should have issued a warning about this type mismatch.  Do not ignore these warnings, they indicate programming errors.  Better even, enable more warnings: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything` will produce more warnings about potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the prototype of `swap` to `void swap(float** a, float** b );`. Then modify the function's definition to:

```
void swap(float** a, float** b) {
    float temp = **a;
    **a = **b;
    **b = temp;
}
```

Comment: More indirection is obviously better. Make it three stars please.

Comment: I mistakenly thought about this as the problem of passing pointers as parameters in C, hence the more convoluted example. Thanks for your *very* lovely comment though.